# DNS api for Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS server higher-level than WMI?

Tags: c#, dns, windows-server-2008, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

I've been writing code over the last day or so that manages a Windows Server 2008 R2 DNS server via the [DNS WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682123.aspx).  Since they're not very developer-friendly in C# (a little friendlier in a dynamic REPL like PowerShell with tab completion), I was trying to find out if someone else had already wrapped the WMI calls into a little library that would be strongly typed and allow at least most of the common cases (creating and deleting zones, creating and deleting records in a zone).  It doesn't have to be third-party, it can be something from Microsoft (maybe there's something on the box I'm missing?)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't now for a wrapper for these classes, but exist several tools which can help you to create code to interact with the WMI.

- The [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) allow you to generate C#, C++ or
  Object pascal code to access the WMI.
- [MgmtClassGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186156.aspx) , This
  tool generates Strongly typed class  for a given WMI class.
- [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/Download/en/details.aspx?id=8572)

Comment: I had completely forgotten about MgmtClassGen!  Thanks!!